# Need to allocate and initialize object if declared in .h file

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is an object allocated and initialized when declared in header file or do I need to alloc and init the object in my implementation?

Which of these is correct?

```
.h

@interface myViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *bgImageView;

@end 

.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
if (!self.bgImageView) {

        NSString *fullpath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/Background.png"];

        self.bgImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullpath];

        [self.view addSubview:self.bgImageView ];
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.bgImageView ];

}
```

or

```
.h

@interface myViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *bgImageView;

@end 

.m 

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
if (!self.bgImageView) {

        NSString *fullpath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/Background.png"];

        self.bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullpath]];

        [self.view addSubview:self.bgImageView ];
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.bgImageView ];

}
```

Comment: second one is correct

Comment: A quick test should have shown that option 1 doesn't work and option 2 does...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object properties are explicitly set to `nil` in Objective-C to avoid the uninitialized object issues that other languages can have.

Non-object properties are set to the zero version (i.e. `CGFloat` is 0.000000, `NSRange` is {0,0}, `BOOL` is NO).

Therefore, your second code is correct, although your first code would work if you had allocated and initialized `self.bgImageView` any time before `self.bgImageView.image = ...` (for example, in the `init` method of your view controller or in `loadView` or even the line above `self.bgImageView.image`).

Comment: Just to mention another possibility for initializing `self.bgImageView`: declaring its property as an `IBOutlet` and configuring the view in the storyboard or xib file.

Answer (score 1):

Put alloc and init in the .m file, only put the @property in .h if some other VC needs to access the object, otherwise just have it in the .m as well.

Test your own code as well, best way to learn